# How to validate joomla lightbox form?

Tags: javascript, validation, joomla, lightbox

I used one module with the help of fancybox in joomla. It contain one contact form. But when I submit the form it does not perform the validation which are in the javascript. May be because javascript does not fetch the value of any textbox...
How to solve this problem in the joomla 1.5 version?

Please reply...
Thank you...

Comment: can you please provide some code snippets

Answer (score 0):

the javascript code need to be loaded with the page itself not with the fancy (popup) box.

if not possible try `window.parent.functioname();`

And check for jQuery.conflict, if you use other than this.

Anyhow could you add some more detail.

Glad to help.